# Data structure, best practice to build true "related by tags" items list?

Tags: data-structures, tags

What I mean saying true "related by tags" list?

Let's imagine that article have 3 tags: A, B, C. True "related by tags" articles for this item will be articles fistly having A, B, C tags, then (A, B), (A, C), (B, C) etc.

**table: tags**

```
tag_id
tag_title
tag_nicetitle
```

**table: tags2articles**

```
article_id
tag_id
```

Using this tables structure is too difficult to calculate true "related by tags".

We can add one more table containing article_id and it's md5(A,B,C). Before hashing we should sort tags by alphabet.

**table: article_tags_hashed**

```
id
article_id
md5
count
```

This table will help us to find articles containing exact set of tags (A,B,C), but it won't help to find articles containing only (A, B), (A, C), (B, C)

What is the best practice?

PS: Sorry for my english, it's pretty bad.

Comment: Are you doing it with SQL and DB or in Java/C++/other imperative language?

Comment: Nope, I'm doing it with PHP/MySQL.
But is there any difference what language I'm using for it?
It seems to me be just a data structure and performance question.

Comment: Well, you don't have any data structures other than tables in DBMS, so you have to craft a query. If you were using an imperative language, you could play with the data structures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need **article_tags_hashed** because you can group and count the results when you
query the **tags2articles**.

Example:

```
select article_id, count(article_id) as tagcnt from tags2articles
where tag_id in (...)
group by article_id
order by tagcnt desc
```

The articles which contain the most tags will be placed first.

Comment: @Kirzilla, if the `id`'s are keys then yes, it should be fast. You can even set a limit for the results. ie you can *ask* to get at most 15 articles.